# fetch records when parameters may be null

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I have search form which contains start date, end date, which are mandatory then we have updatedBy and status which are non mandatory, I have written JPA query for that as

```
select c from Entity c 
where c.status=:status 
  and c.updatedBy=:updatedBy 
  and c.startDate>=:startDate 
  and c.endDate:<= c.endDate
```

this query is returning error when values in non mandatory fields are null, I need help in re writting the query to fetch results if serach parameter contains null values, in my case updatedBy and status may be null.

Comment: can you show the fields Of Entity?

Comment: Its a simple table without any relationship , so that fields may be: 1. StartDate 2. EndDate, 3. Id 4. UpdatedBy , 5. Status

Comment: Can I pass the field name also by which I need to orderBy, actualy the request to order by can come from front end and I need to update the same query. Will I have to write separate query for different OrderBy or it can be done in same query

Comment: yes you can use the `ORDER BY` clause in jpa query

Comment: their are 5 field, so will I have to write five different query for sorting the same or it can be done in one query only by modifing the query that you have suggested 1. select c.StartDate, c.EndDate, c.Id, c.UpdatedBy , coalesce(c.Status,0) 
from Entity c where c.status=:status and c.updatedBy=:updatedBy 
and c.startDate>=:startDate and c.endDate:<= c.endDate OrderBy c.status 2. select c.StartDate, c.EndDate, c.Id, c.UpdatedBy , coalesce(c.Status,0) 
from Entity c where c.status=:status and c.updatedBy=:updatedBy 
and c.startDate>=:startDate and c.endDate:<= c.endDate orderBy c.UpdatedBy etc

Comment: it can be down in one query, you can comment in below answer also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for none mandatory fields use `coalesce` to not return null or modify the entity to accept nulls for them(the first solution is prefered) for example if Status is nullable use:

```
select c.StartDate, c.EndDate, c.Id, c.UpdatedBy , coalesce(c.Status,0) 
from Entity c where c.status=:status and c.updatedBy=:updatedBy 
and c.startDate>=:startDate and c.endDate:<= c.endDate
Order by c.StartDate, c.EndDate, c.Id, c.UpdatedBy , coalesce(c.Status,0)
```

Comment: can you show me in the above query how can I pass the orderBy clause for multiple fields

Comment: when user clicks on the column name of startDate then the request will be commimg for OrderBy c.startDate , when the user clicks of the end date column name then the request will be comming for OrderBy c.EndDate and so on, will this query work in that case

Comment: in that case you can use the `@OrderColumn` annotation in your entity

Comment: actually @orderColumn will not work in that case , can you tell the solution by using specification and predicate

Comment: just see your question and problem in the post, what have you asked? and know you are going to discuss on whole JPA, I'm really sorry I have not more time.

Comment: I deeply regret to bother you so much, but thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: you are very welcome, no problem, hope your questions go solved. good luck